# How to align the flex items in three different ways?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

[image]

So, I want to align items inside flex-box like in the above picture.

I have html as follows:

```
<div class="flex-row">
  <div class="flex-item">
    <img src="/default.png">
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <img src="/default.png">
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <img src="/default.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

css as

```
   .flex-row {
      min-height: 400px;
      display: flex;
      align-items: flex-start;
   }

   .flex-item:nth-child(2) {
     align-items: center;
   }

   .flex-item:last-child {
      align-items: flex-end;
   }
```

Comment: you can follow this link: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Your edit with the new image now shows, what you really want to achieve. Paulie_D has the right answer on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `align-self` not `align-items`

```css
.flex-row {
  min-height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 1em auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.flex-item {
  height: 50px;
  background: lightblue;
  width: 100px;
}

.flex-item:nth-child(2) {
  align-self: center;
}

.flex-item:last-child {
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="container flex-row">
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not to forget `justify-content: space-between;`

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE!**

to set height to column change the `px` here:`flex: 0 1 50px;` or remove it!

1. **Using `margin-right/left:auto` as:**

   ```css
   .flex-row {
     min-height: 400px;
     display: flex;
     flex-wrap: wrap;
     flex-direction: column;
   }

   .flex-item {
     flex: 0 1 50px;

   }

   .flex-item:nth-child(2) {
     margin-right: auto;
     margin-left: auto;
   }
   .flex-item:last-child {
     margin-left: auto;
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <div class="flex-row">
     <div class="flex-item">
       <img src="/default.png">
     </div>
     <div class="flex-item">
       <img src="/default.png">
     </div>
     <div class="flex-item">
       <img src="/default.png">
     </div>
   </div>
   ```

**2. using `align-self`**

```css
.flex-row {
  min-height: 400px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.flex-item {
  flex: 0 1 50px;
  align-self: flex-start;
}

.flex-item:nth-child(2) {
  align-self: center;
}

.flex-item:last-child {
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-row">
  <div class="flex-item">
    <img src="/default.png">
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <img src="/default.png">
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <img src="/default.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: tell me for more help

Comment: Thank you for answer but, there was miscommunication, I have changed the picture of my question. Please can you help.

Comment: All you have to do is to change the `px` here :`flex: 0 1 100px;`  or remove it

Answer (score 0):

Like so?
You need `flex-wrap: wrap;` In order to wrap the items need to be wide enough (100%). Since 100% flex item is always justified to the full width, you need `text-align`, not `align-items` which is the wrong property in the first place.

`align-items` is the alignment at the cross axis, not the main axis which would be `justify-content`

```css
.flex-row {
  min-height: 400px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex-item {
  flex-basis: 100%;
}
.flex-item:nth-child(2) {
  text-align: center;
}

.flex-item:last-child {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-row">
  <div class="flex-item">
    <img src="/default.png" width="100" height="50">
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <img src="/default.png" width="100" height="50">
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <img src="/default.png" width="100" height="50">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this code

```
display:flex;
flex-direction: row;
justify-content: flex-start; 
align-items: centre;
```

With `flex-direction` you specify le principal alignment (horizontal with `row` , vertical with `column`). Depending on what you choose here the following properties will have a different effect.

Then with `justify-content` you specify how your items inside your elements should align **on the principal axis you just defined** (vertical or horizontal).
In this case `flex-start` means at the beginning of my axis.

And with `align-items` you specify the **alignment for the secondary axe**.The vertical one because we choose `flex-direction: row;` and not `flex-direction: column;`. So in the vertical axis items will align at `centre`

And don't forget to take look at the available properties like `space-between` or `flex-end`